# How to keep the abbreviation dot in journal field of bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

The abbreviation dot in journal field was omitted. How can I maintain it?

Here is my main.tex:

```
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{vancouver.bst}
\bibliography{abbr.bib}
\end{document}
```

In abbr.bib file:

```
@Article{buchfink2015fast,
  author    = {Buchfink, Benjamin and Xie, Chao and Huson, Daniel H},
  journal   = {Nat. Methods},
  title     = {Fast and sensitive protein alignment using DIAMOND},
  year      = {2015},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {59--60},
  volume    = {12},
  publisher = {Nature Publishing Group},
}
```

Compile:

> Buchﬁnk B, Xie C, Huson DH. Fast and sensitive protein alignment using
> DIAMOND. **Nat Methods.** 2015;12(1):59–60

I Expect '**Nat. Methods.**' not 'Nat Methods.'

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. This has to do with the style you are using `vancouver.bst`. This problem was not duplicated using the generic BibTex styles. Please supply the file, and also, to help us help you, fix the code so it we could compile it and recreate the problem on our side (i.e. remove `...` add `\documentclass` and any relevant packages).

Answer (score 2):

The bibstyle vancouver.bst has a function remove.dots, which (as its name suggests) removes dots from author and journal names. If you want to keep the dots, you will have to modify the bibstyle to not call remove.dots inside the format.journal.date and article functions.

Comment: Many Thanks, I the % remove.dots line and the dot appear!